# S3 Replication Between Regions

Tags: amazon-s3

I search a way to replicate between S3 buckets across regions.

The purpose is that if a file accidentally deleted because a bug in my application, I would be able to restore it from the other bucket.

There is any way to do it without upload the file twice (meaning, not in the application layer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set versioning on your S3 Bucket. After that it will keep all version files which you uploaded or updated in S3 Bucket. After that you can restore any version of file from version listing. See - [Amazon S3 Object Lifecycle Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)